# How to select distinct latest datetime?

Tags: sql

Here is a sample of my `Table A` and its code. Do note that the `equip_OID` is different.

Table A:

| Workstation | ID | WS_OID | equip_OID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WS 3-ABC21 | ABC21 | 0x8008C14353564545 | 0x9454863AA56474 |
| WS 3-ABC21 | ABC21 | 0x8008C14353564545 | 0x9454863BB56474 |

```
select distinct
    trim(ws.WS_name) as [Workstation],
    substring(trim(e.equip_id),1,8) as [ID],
    eqmhist.WS_OID,
    eqmhist.equip_OID
into 
    #Table_A
from
    eqmhist
inner join 
    e on eqmhist.equip_OID = e.equip_OID
inner join 
    ws on ws.WS_OID = eqmhist.WS_OID
inner join 
    a on a.mfg_area_OID = e.mfg_area_OID
```

I joined Table A with Table B as it has the `[tracked_out_datetime]` that I need, I inner joined using `[ID]` and `[Tool ID]`  to get my Table C:

Table C:

| Workstation | Tool ID | WS_OID | equip_OID | tracked_out_datetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WS 3-ABC21 | ABC21 | 0x8008C14353564545 | 0x9454863AA56474 | 2023-01-04 21:28:42.000 |
| WS 3-ABC21 | ABC21 | 0x8008C14353564545 | 0x9454863AA56474 | 2023-01-05 03:06:26.000 |
| WS 3-ABC21 | ABC21 | 0x8008C14353564545 | 0x9454863AA56474 | 2023-01-05 10:22:18.000 |
| WS 3-ABC21 | ABC21 | 0x8008C14353564545 | 0x9454863BB56474 | 2023-02-14 17:20:42.000 |
| WS 3-ABC21 | ABC21 | 0x8008C14353564545 | 0x9454863BB56474 | 2023-02-14 19:11:43.000 |
| WS 3-ABC21 | ABC21 | 0x8008C14353564545 | 0x9454863BB56474 | 2023-01-30 16:15:04.000 |

```
select distinct
    ta.[WS Name],
    substring(trim(tracking_interface_id), 1, 8) as [Tool],
    ta.equip_OID,
    ta.WS_OID,
    tracked_out_datetime
into 
    #Table_C
from  
    Table_B tb
inner join 
    #Table_A ta on substring((tb.tracking_interface_id),1,8) = ta.[Equid ID]
where 
    exists (select taa.[Equid ID] from #Table_A taa 
            where taa.[Equid ID] = substring((tb.tracking_interface_id), 1, 8))
```

What I'm trying to do is to select the latest `[tracked_out_datetime]` for each distinct `[equip_OID]`. But the problem that I'm facing now is that the code I tried only showed me the latest `[track_out_datetime]` but without the distinct `[equip_OID]`, I can't seem to fix it. Hope I can get some advice from you experts! The code, problem faced and my desired result will be below.

Code:

```
select
    x.[WS Name],
    x.[Tool],
    x.WS_OID,
    x.equip_OID,
    tracked_out_datetime
into 
    #main2
from
    (select 
         ta.[WS Name], 
         substring(trim(tracking_interface_id),1,8) as [Tool],
         ta.equip_OID, 
         ta.WS_OID, 
         tb.tracked_out_datetime,
         row_number() over(partition by tracking_interface_id order by tracked_out_datetime desc) as rn
     from 
         Table_B tb
     inner join 
         #Table_A ta on substring((tb.tracking_interface_id), 1, 8) = ta.[Equid ID]
     where 
         exists (select taa.[Equid ID] from #Table_A taa 
                 where taa.[Equid ID] = substring((tb.tracking_interface_id), 1, 8))) x
where 
    x.rn = 1 

select distinct * 
from #main2
```

Problem:

| Workstation | ID | WS_OID | equip_OID | tracked_out_datetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WS 3-ABC21 | ABC21 | 0x8008C14353564545 | 0x9454863BB56474 | 2023-02-14 19:11:43.000 |

(only showing the latest)

Desired result:

| Workstation | ID | WS_OID | equip_OID | tracked_out_datetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WS 3-ABC21 | ABC21 | 0x8008C14353564545 | 0x9454863AA56474 | 2023-01-05 10:22:18.000 |
| WS 3-ABC21 | ABC21 | 0x8008C14353564545 | 0x9454863BB56474 | 2023-02-14 19:11:43.000 |

Comment: Use `Group by` and `Having` statements. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: @RezaNoei where do i add it into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try to add here:

```
row_number() over(partition by tracking_interface_id order by tracked_out_datetime desc) as rn
```

the `equip_OID` like this:

```
 ... partition by tracking_interface_id, equip_OID oder by ...
```

Answer (score 0):

distinct doesn't works because u have different values on `[tracked_out_datetime]`. if you remove this column from your query distinct works fine. but it won't help you. because you want this column of course.

I wanted to use `Group by` and `Having` pair. but there is an easier solution.

```
 select distinct
     ta.[WS Name],
     substring(trim(tracking_interface_id), 1, 8) as [Tool],
     ta.equip_OID,
     ta.WS_OID,
    (SELECT Max(tracked_out_datetime) FROM #Table_A
    WHERE exist (select taa.[Equid ID] from #Table_A taa where taa.[Equid ID] = substring((tb.tracking_interface_id), 1, 8))
          AND #Table_A.equip_OID = ta.[Equid ID]) AS max_tracked_out_datetime

 into 
     #Table_C
 from
     Table_B tb
 inner join 
     #Table_A ta on substring((tb.tracking_interface_id),1,8) = ta.[Equid ID]
 where 
     exists (select taa.[Equid ID] from #Table_A taa 
             where taa.[Equid ID] = substring((tb.tracking_interface_id), 1, 8))
```

here is the trick:

```
 (SELECT Max(tracked_out_datetime) FROM #Table_A
WHERE exist (select taa.[Equid ID] from #Table_A taa where taa.[Equid ID] = substring((tb.tracking_interface_id), 1, 8))
      AND #Table_A.equip_OID = ta.[Equid ID]) AS max_tracked_out_datetime
```

I just said: Find maximum value for `tracking_out_datetime` for each `equip_OID`. It will results in duplicated lanes which `distinct` is able to reduce them now.